# Ipython notebook remote server on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook

I'm running a remote IPython notebook server on an EC2 instance on AWS. The instance is running Ubuntu.
Followed [this](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/public_server.html) tutorial to set up, and everything seems to work - I can access the notebook via https with a password and run code.

However, I can't seem to save changes to the notebook - It says "saving notebook" and then nothing happens (i.e, still written 'unsaved changes' on top).

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: It's not a permissions problem, since running in sudo doesn't help.
When creating a new notebook in the remote server, I am able to save. Problem only occurs for notebooks pulled from my git repository. Also, when opening a problematic notebook, and deleting all cells until it's absolutely empty, I can sometimes (!) save the empty notebook, and sometimes (!!) I still can't.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered an issue where notebooks wouldn't save on the nbserver on AWS EC2 instance I set up in a similar manner via different tutorial. It turns out I had to refresh and **re-login** using the password, because my browser would automatically log out have a certain period. Might help if you close and re-attempt to go the the nbserver and see if it asks you to re-login.

Here's a few other things you can try:

- try to copy a problematic notebook into the server (scp) and try to open+save, as opposed to going thru repo pull to see if anything changes
- check if the hanging "saving notebook" message appear for notebooks in certain directories
- check the ipython console messages when you save a problematic notebook and see if anything there can help you pinpoint the issue